# Android broadcast receiver isn't receiving explicit broadcast?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get add a background service to an Android app I'm working on. I followed [this guide](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android) for adding the service and getting it to restart in the background when the main activity is destroyed. This didn't work as it was shown in the guide because (I think) I needed to make the broadcast explicit (described [here](https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a)). I attempted to do so by adding this to my service's constructor:

```
applicationContext.registerReceiver(
    new LocationSyncServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver(),
    new IntentFilter("com.company.AppName.RestartLocationSyncService")
);
```

After adding this, when I close the app it no longer throws a failed broadcast error, but it also doesn't appear to run `LocationSyncServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver.onReceive` (or it's just not showing up in the logs).

This is how I'm creating the background service (from within `MainActivity`):

```
private void startLocationSyncService() {
  ctx = this;
  mLocationSyncService = new LocationSyncService(getCtx());
  mLocationSyncServiceIntent = new Intent(getCtx(), mLocationSyncService.getClass());
  if (!isServiceRunning(mLocationSyncService.getClass())) {
    startService(mLocationSyncServiceIntent);
  }
}

private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", true+"");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", false+"");
    return false;
}
```

And here is my background service:

```
package com.company.AppName;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocationSyncService extends Service {
  private static final String TAG = "LocationSyncService";
  private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
  private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
  private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

  LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
      new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
      new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
  };

  public LocationSyncService() {}
  public LocationSyncService(Context applicationContext) {
    super();
    Log.i(TAG, "created");
    applicationContext.registerReceiver(
        new LocationSyncServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver(),
        new IntentFilter("com.company.AppName.RestartLocationSyncService")
    );
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBind");
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    return START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
      mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
          LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
          mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
      Log.e(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
      Log.e(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
      mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
          LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
          mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
      Log.e(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
      Log.e(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.i(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
      mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.company.AppName.RestartLocationSyncService");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
  }

  private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
  {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
      Log.i(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
      mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
      Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
      mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
      Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
      Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
      Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
  }
}
```

And the broadcast receiver that is supposed to restart the service:

```
package com.company.AppName;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocationSyncServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final String TAG = "RestarterBcastReceiver";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "----- onReceive!!!");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationSyncService.class));
  }
}
```

And my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.company.AppName" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.company.AppName.LocationSyncService" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:label="RestartLocationSyncServiceWhenStopped" android:name="com.company.AppName.LocationSyncServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.company.AppName.RestartLocationSyncService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to call `setComponent` on the intent being sent to the broadcast receiver from the service's `onDestroy` method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.company.AppName.RestartLocationSyncService");
  broadcastIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.company.AppName", "com.company.AppName.LocationSyncServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver"));
  sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just more simple way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("TEST");
intent.setPackage( getPackageName() );
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot send implicit broadcast or implicit intent – first check the ComponentName. the package name must be the application ID and not the package name you can see in your receiver class.

Look for the application id in build.gradle:

```
             defaultConfig {
                            applicationId "com.my.app.id.name"
```

or in  auto generated buildConfig.java file after build:

app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\release\

```
             package com.my.app.id.name;
```

For example if your class name is “MyExplicitReciver”
and the package name you can see in the first line of this class is

```
            package com.my.app.myPackage.name.receivers;
```

so the class name should be :
                 com.my.app.myPackage.name.receivers.MyExplicitReciver

and you should set compoonent name like this in setComponent:

```
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.my.app.id.name",
    "com.my.app.myPackage.name.receivers"));
            context().sendBroadcast(intent);
```